# Modify rustc's AST and continue the compilation with the modified AST

Tags: rust, compilation, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to modify the AST generated by rustc's parser, then continue the compilation with the modified AST?

To be specific, I am looking for a function like `rustc_driver::Callbacks::after_analysis`, which is called after the type checking is done. But this API only lets you instruct the compiler to continue or stop. In my case, I want to modify the AST and let the compiler continue the compilation with this new AST. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: You would have to modify the AST, re-typecheck, then continue. I'm not sure if there is a way. Why can't you modify the AST before typecheck?

Comment: Sounds exactly like a [proc macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html). The docs literally say, "You can sort of think of procedural macros as functions from an AST to another AST."

Comment: @PitaJ I might want to utilize the typing information in the AST modification. Btw, is there a way to modify the AST before typecheck and continue the compilation? Still useful for me if such an approach exists.

Comment: @isaactfa The issue with proc-macro is that I need some global information to determine the modification, which is similar to the case discussed at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44034.